# using useSystemProperties for apache camel http component

Tags: apache-camel

According to [apache camel document](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/http-component.html)
useSystemProperties  could be used as query param for http component like below shown

https://URL ?useSystemProperties=true

But I want to use do it via API(method) way. Is it possible and how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "via API(method) way"? Do you mean that you want to enable it programmatically?

Comment: Yes, programmatically configure it